# Не удается найти указанный файл, хотя он существует

Tags: c#

Используется библиотека GLNFS.dll, лежит в корне диска D (т. е. по пути нет кириллицы), доступ к ней пользователь "СИСТЕМА" имеет, однако visual studio 2013 (а точнее cosmos user kit) не может найти файл!
Вот лог компиляции:

```
Project: MeduzeBoot, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>  IL2CPU invoked with DebugMode='Source', DebugEnabled='False', TraceAssemblies='{NULL}', IgnoreDebugStub='False'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Cosmos\Cosmos.targets(31,5): error : Could not load file or assembly 'GLNFS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Не удается найти указанный файл.
1>   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveField(RuntimeModule module, Int32 fieldToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack retField)
1>   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveFieldHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 fieldToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
1>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveField(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
1>   at Cosmos.IL2CPU.ILReader.ProcessMethod(MethodBase aMethod) in g:\IL2CPU\source2\IL2CPU\Cosmos.IL2CPU\ILReader.cs:line 320
1>   at Cosmos.IL2CPU.ILScanner.ScanMethod(MethodBase aMethod, Boolean aIsPlug, String sourceItem) in g:\IL2CPU\source2\IL2CPU\Cosmos.IL2CPU\ILScanner.cs:line 561
1>   at Cosmos.IL2CPU.ILScanner.ScanQueue() in g:\IL2CPU\source2\IL2CPU\Cosmos.IL2CPU\ILScanner.cs:line 686
1>   at Cosmos.IL2CPU.ILScanner.Execute(MethodBase aStartMethod) in g:\IL2CPU\source2\IL2CPU\Cosmos.IL2CPU\ILScanner.cs:line 277
1>   at Cosmos.Build.MSBuild.IL2CPUTask.Execute() in g:\IL2CPU\source2\Build\Cosmos.Build.MSBuild\IL2CPUTask.cs:line 239
1>  IL2CPU task took 00:00:00.4640086
1>Done building project "MeduzeBoot.Cosmos" -- FAILED.
1>
Build has been canceled.
```

Как исправить проблему?

Comment: Возможно эту библиотеку нужно переместить в папку с проектом либо импортировать в проект

Comment: В References библиотека добавлена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть [похожий пост](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.cosmos.devel/5045) на сайте разработчиков, где обсуждается ошибки при билде с этой библиотекой.

Возможно, библиотека вообще не в стабильном релизе, поскольку там пишут

> GLNFS is a project done by one of our users. It's not part of the main project.

Может у неё есть какие-либо зависимости, которые не находятся при сборке.

Наверное, можно поинтересоваться у автора библиотеки или тех, кто с ним работает в Cosmos-Dev.

Comment: Спасибо, в таком случае, где бы скачать исходники библиотеки? Гугл ссылку не выдаёт.

Comment: Лучше использовать встроенные средства для работы с FAT. https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos/issues/64